# BCS, can I connect a result of SQL query to external database in SharePoint list?

Tags: bcs, sql, content-source

Can I connect a result of SQL query to external database in SharePoint list?

As I understand - External Content types could map only one table for list, but I need to get some combined data from **few** tables, not single one. So I am trying to get result with "Content Source" in SPD, it allows queries as I understand.

By example I have external database with tables 'CountryRegion' and 'SomeTable', screenshots are below:

[image]

[image]

I make some logic in query and get result, by example

```
SELECT *
 FROM AdventureWorks2008.Person.CountryRegion R
 INNER JOIN
AdventureWorks2008.dbo.SomeTable T
 ON R.CountryRegionCode = T.CountryRegionCode
```

I get this result:

[image]

Now I created "Content Source" in  SharePoint Designer, it allowed me to make this select query:

[image]

But how can I map this result to SharePoint list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also like to add that you can also accomplish this with SQL Table Views.  So if you create a custom view within your SQL DB, you can connect to it in BCS using SP Designer as if it was a regular table.  My understanding is that if the View is update-able as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)#Read-only_vs._updatable_views), you will also be able to add Update controls to it.  To add a view as an ECT please follow the steps here: http://prairiedeveloper.com/?p=395  However, instead of adding your operations to the table, you can now add the operations to the view instead (Step 3 in Map Parameters).

Just another suggestion to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stored procedures with BCS, so instead of a single table, you can gather information (Read only) from a result of a query. You need to create the stored procedure in SQL first, then connect to BCS through SHarePoint Designer, then you will be able to create a External Content Type based on that stored procedure.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jysaikia/archive/2010/12/15/a-step-by-step-guide-in-designing-bcs-entities-by-using-a-sql-stored-procedure.aspx#CreateECT) is an article that explains it a bit better.